# Forms samples with 960 grid

Tags: 960.gs

I've decided to use the 960 grid for a project and would like some samples/examples for doing stacked (label above data field) forms (with multiple fields per line in situations like phone number) with room for validation messages.

Anyone have any good examples? I like the Woo Forms but they aren't built around this framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really think here google is your friend here.

There are a ton of ways to do web forms.  I too like [Woo Forms](http://wufoo.com/gallery/designs/2/) as they are nicely done.  I have not looked at it too much but you can get their themes and take a look at how they accomplish things.

Take a look at this [formee](http://www.formee.org/) or [uni-form](http://sprawsm.com/uni-form/), which may help you.  It deals with forms using the 960 grid system.
A couple of other sites that are pretty good to help you:[net.tuts Mastering grid 960](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/mastering-the-960-grid-system/),  [cssnewbie](http://www.cssnewbie.com/),  [css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/), [20 Jquery forms plugins](http://speckyboy.com/2009/08/26/20-jquery-plugins-and-tutorials-to-enhance-forms/), [Jquery form 100 best plugins](http://www.webdesignshock.com/jquery-forms-plugins-tutorials/)